# How can I make a version of this script start up after reboots?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have this one batch file that runs:

```
for /R C:\some\Directory\target\ %%f in (*.bat) do (call "%%f")
```

It eventually loops over a bat file and has to reboot is there a way for it keeps looping after the reboot? I was reading on SuperUser something like resume however I do not see it implemented so quickly here. Is there any way to implement it? The script is meant to be called and install software on a device, but it stops after the reboot. Is there a way to keep the batch file executing the other software?

Comment: If you have a Pro Version of Windows you can try putting the script in C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logon  and use Group Policy to activate the script.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1215057/1737567
 
 Break the script down to 2 or more different (.bat) files (depending
 on how many loops you want it to have), and then you can make a batch
 file edit a registry entry so that it includes the second batch file
 name and path (which needs to be executed when the computer restarts).
 the registry entry that needs to be altered is this :
 `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce` and the value
 of that registry entry should be changed to the second batch file
 location (so on applies to the second batch file too)

Comment: Cool question bro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_batch_dir=C:\some\Directory\target"
set "_KeyRunOnce=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"

if not "%~1" == "" (set "_skp=skip=%~1" && set "_count=%~1")else set "_count=1"

for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s /aa "%_batch_dir%\*.bat" ^| find /v /c ""')do set /a "_total=%%~i"

for /f "%_skp% delims=" %%i in ('2^>nul where.exe /r "%_batch_dir%" "*.bat"')do if !_count! lss !_total! =;(
     reg add "%_KeyRunOnce%" /v "%~n0" /d "\"%~f0\" \"!_count!\"" /f && set /a "_count+=1" );= 1>nul 2>&1 & call "%%~i"

1>nul 2>&1 reg delete "%_KeyRunOnce%" /v "%~n0" /f & endlocal
```

---

**1.** Start by counting the total of your bat files to run

**2.** Obtained the total, check if the current execution is the initial, interval or last

**3.** Add a counter and through that, execute the value of the counter and use that indicator for the relevant continuity execution.

**4.** Define which bat to start, continue and end with the argument and `RunOnce` key suggested by [@tabby.sl](https://superuser.com/users/1737567/tabby-sl)

**5.** Replace `For /R` to `For /F` and use counter as argument in RunOnce, and use argument as `skip` in your `For /F skip=Argument`